# OpenCV 3.x only contains one lib - opencv_world.lib?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv3.0

I'm trying to update my OpenCV version from 2.4.9 to the newest version, 3.10. I downloaded the Windows binary from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0/), having navigated there from the official OpenCV site. I then ran the installer, but the `opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib` directory only contained a couple files:

- opencv_world310.lib
- opencv_world310d.lib
- OpenCVConfig.cmake
- OpenCVModules.cmake
- OpenCVModules-debug.cmake
- OpenCVModules-release.cmake

In the past editions though, this directory used to contain the required libraries, like opencv_calib3d249d.lib, opencv_contrib249d.lib, opencv_core249d.lib, etc.

I imagine there's something I need to do with CMake, but I can't seem to figure it out--the old binaries used to compile everything for you. I also can't find anything in the documentation explaining this. Has anyone else come across this recently and have a solution?

Comment: opencv_world.lib contains all other modules (like core,highgui,etc) , just link to that single lib, and stop worrying

Comment: Oh well that would make sense, thanks. Unless I'm really poor at searching, it seems strange that such a major change isn't broadcasted more obviously though.

Comment: So, what is the difference between opencv_world310.lib and opencv_world310d.lib? Is it related to debugging? Should I link to both of them?

Comment: @r_laezza: Link against `opencv_world310d.lib` in debug mode and link against `opencv_world310.lib` in release mode. If you compile the individual libraries, the same convention holds `opencv_*d.lib` is for debug, while `opencv_*.lib` is for release.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, the binary version of OpenCV-3.x doesn't contain the separate libs like `opencv_core.lib`. Instead, these modules are integrated in `opencv_world.lib`, so you only need to link to it.

On the other hand, if you do want separate libs, i.e. uniform APIs with OpenCV-2.x, you can build it yourself using CMake by enable the libs that you want. Like

[image]

This will generate `opencv_core.lib`.

Comment: The advantage to this being you can keep your overall package size smaller by only including the OpenCV libs that you require. Not sure there is a lot of point in this day and age though...

Answer (score 1):

Or run cmake with `-D BUILD_opencv_world=OFF` key