# undefined reference when linking - missing libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, mingw

I am using OpenCV 3.1 for Windows, MinGW, NetBeans.

According to this there should be just one OpenCV library that integrates multitude of other ones:

[OpenCV 3.x only contains one lib - opencv_world.lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867289/opencv-3-x-only-contains-one-lib-opencv-world-lib)

I am trying to use the pre-built libraries:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable

Linking:

> g++     -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/program_name
>   build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o
>   -L../../../lib/opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib -lopencv_world310

And I am getting a lot of errors like this:

```
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
```

Something I would expect after not including opencv_core and such - but as I understand they all should be in opencv_world310 now.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you need to build with `cmake` before using ....after build you will find all the libs & dlls ...original source do not contain pre-built libraries like earlier version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using OpenCV built with vc14 (Visual Studio 2015) compiler:

> L../../../lib/opencv/build/x64/**vc14**/lib

You need to rebuild OpenCV with MinGW, and link to it.