# Crosscompiling VisualGDB/C++ Cubietruck => Linkererror

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cross-compiling, visualgdb

i am trying to get an **opencv c++** program, which runs on my laptop, on my hardware - furthermore i should mention, that i am new to embedded programming.
May someone can help me, because i got problems while cross-compiling with **VisualGDB**. I am using following board: Cubieboard 3 (**Cubietruck**- Dual-Core A20)

The toolchain is stored locally - so not on the board itself.
All libraries are included and detected in Visual Studio --> take a look at the Screenshot:

[image]

The "**opencv_world320d.lib**" - Library includes all the needed sub libraries - i found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867289/opencv-3-x-only-contains-one-lib-opencv-world-lib)

The C++ code itself:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 100)); //create an image ( 3 channels, 8 bit image depth, 500 high, 1000 wide, (0, 0, 100) assigned for Blue, Green and Red plane respectively. )

    if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
    imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

    waitKey(0);  //wait infinite time for a keypress

    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build the linker fails with following message:

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: LinuxProject2, Konfiguration: Debug VisualGDB ------
1>  Linking VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2...
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd.hpp(622): error : undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvstd.hpp(664): error : undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp(352): error : undefined reference to `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp(592): error : undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp(684): error : undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
1>C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp(704): error : undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
1>  VisualGDB/Debug/LinuxProject2.o: In function `main':
1>D:\Softwareentwicklung\Projects\LinuxProject2\LinuxProject2.cpp(18): error : undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
1>D:\Softwareentwicklung\Projects\LinuxProject2\LinuxProject2.cpp(19): error : undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
1>D:\Softwareentwicklung\Projects\LinuxProject2\LinuxProject2.cpp(21): error : undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
1>D:\Softwareentwicklung\Projects\LinuxProject2\LinuxProject2.cpp(23): error : undefined reference to `cv::destroyWindow(cv::String const&)'
1>collect2.exe : error : ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe someone had the same problems - i really searched a lot, but i wasn't able to find similar issues.

Comment: Thanks to SO not letting me flag after retracting one that the OP made obsolete, I can't formally flag this, but: Possible duplicate of [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)

Answer (score 0):

You have only told the toolchain *where* to look when searching for libraries ("Library directory"). You have not told it **which** libraries to link to... So it not being able to find any symbols from those missing libraries is completely unsurprising.

So, in addition to the library search directory/ies, you also need to populate the "Library names" field with the names of any libraries whose symbols you are referencing - in this case, at least `opencv`. That way, the linker can link to those libraries and therefore resolve those symbols.

**Edit as per now-completely-different question**

Based on this thread:
[Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)
It looks like you should move any static libraries into the "Additional linker" flags, as the "Library names" generates `-l` switches (not `-l:`), which are for dynamic libraries, but you are trying to link a static library.

Comment: I have tried this before - i linked everything like in the existing,running program. But the linker can't find that library file. I updated the screenshot and the output.

Comment: Great, so now you've changed the question from underneath me. /sigh

Comment: I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867289/opencv-3-x-only-contains-one-lib-opencv-world-lib
Here it is mentioned that there should only that one library linked.
i have put it now into "Additional Linker" : C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world320d.lib

But nevertheless i get a lot of " undefined references".

Comment: Please edit your question with any updates like this, rather than posting them in comments. Comments are to be considered ephemeral, prone to disappearing at any moment, and besides, it's not useful to leave up an outdated question and expect readers to pick through comments to get the latest state of things.